# Настройка tomcat на разные порты

Tags: tomcat, порты

Есть `ROOT.war`, работает по `localhost:8080`. Как можно сделать, чтобы было еще одно приложение и оно работало на другом порту, `localhost:8081`, например?

Так мне не подходит: 
`localhost:8080/app1 localhost:8080/app2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Позволю себе не согласиться с более ранним ответом на этот вопрос. Это можно сделать без поддоменов и нескольких копий *Tomcat*. Для этого достаточно создать в *Tomcat* дополнительные сервисы и в каждом из них разместить файл `ROOT.war`.

Пусть структура каталогов *Tomcat* содержит следующие (под)каталоги:

```
...
server8180
server8181
...
webapps
...
```

Каталог `webapps` является базовым по умолчанию для приложений. *Tomcat* (опять-таки по умолчанию) делает доступными приложения из этого каталога по порту 8080. Предположим, мы хотим, чтобы приложения из `server8180` были доступны по порту `8180`, а из `server8181` - по порту `8181`. Для этого добавляем в секцию `Server` конфигурационного файла *Tomcat* (`conf/server.xml`) следующее:

```
<Service name="server8180">
    <Connector port="8180" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Host name="localhost"  appBase="server8180" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" />
    </Engine>
</Service>
<Service name="server8181">
    <Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Host name="localhost"  appBase="server8181" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" />
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

Эти сервисы будут полностью независимыми. Чтобы доступ к какому-либо приложению осуществлялся без указания его имени в адресной строке, достаточно упаковать его в файл с именем `ROOT.war` и разместить в соответствующем каталоге.

P.S. Проверено на `apache-tomcat-8.0.30-windows-x86`.

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что и надо

Answer (score 2):

В Вашем случае используется рутовый контекст, так что запрос на любые настроенные порты приведет к одному и тому же приложению. Можете запустить параллельно несколько tomcat-ов, либо настроить поддомены на разные приложения